# ACS and Azure AD. Different Subscriptions. AADSTS70001: Application was not found in directory

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, azure-acs

I try to integrate Sharepoint with Azure AD using [Using Microsoft Azure Active Directory for SharePoint 2013 authentication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn635311.aspx).

The problem encountered when logging comes from `login.microsoftonline.com` and is:

```
AADSTS70001: Application with identifier 'https://myname.accesscontrol.windows.net/' was not found in the directory 62efceea-b938-4129-9e53-839f774d23e8
```

But I can see it when I use:

```
Get-msolserviceprincipal


ExtensionData         : System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
AccountEnabled        : True
Addresses             : {Microsoft.Online.Administration.RedirectUri}
AppPrincipalId        : c07cade5-ef92-44bf-bfdf-6ea18e8b22a8
DisplayName           : Catapult Staffing
ObjectId              : c3f4832d-d191-4ef7-9d5e-52329d4f903c
ServicePrincipalNames : {c07cade5-ef92-44bf-bfdf-6ea18e8b22a8, https://myname.accesscontrol.windows.net/}
TrustedForDelegation  : False
```

Here is the thing:
We have Azure AD and Access Control Services under different subscriptions. Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I connect ACS to Azure AD through `New-MsolServicePrincipal`, it doesn't create any app reference. Thus, my ACS doesn't appear as Application in Azure AD. Moreover, I'm not able to add it as application manually unless I use `Remove-MsolServicePrincipal`. So there is no need to use it at all!

To get things working I just added 'https://myname.accesscontrol.windows.net/' as an application for my Azure AD. Then viewed endpoints of the newly created app. And used Federation metadata endpoint in as my ACS provider's Url